# What's the current way of KStreamBuilder.from in kafka stream?

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm trying sample codes from http://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/streams/KafkaStreams.html

but for this two lines

```java
KStreamBuilder builder = new KStreamBuilder();
builder.from("my-input-topic").mapValue(value -> value.length().toString()).to("my-output-topic");
```

There seems no method called 'from' in KStreamBuilder now according to https://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KStreamBuilder.html

So what's the current way to do the same thing as the above 2 lines?

Maven is used to manage the dependencies

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
  <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
  <version>0.10.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method was renamed to `stream()` (*from()* is an old name)

```java
KStreamBuilder builder = new KStreamBuilder();
builder.stream("my-input-topic").mapValues(value -> value.length().toString()).to("my-output-topic");
```

It's a bug in the documentation: https://github.com/apache/kafka/pull/1450

Also have a look here: http://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/streams/developer-guide.html#kafka-streams-dsl

Comment: Thank you @Matthias. I guess it should be mapValues but not mapValue, right?

Comment: Yes. Also a typo in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

What's more, the `KStreamBuilder` itself is deprecated now and `StreamsBuilder` should be used instead. It's a quite a bit more than just a name change although for most cases, end-users will not need anything else immediately, [apart from the name of the class](https://kafka.apache.org/20/documentation/streams/upgrade-guide#streams_api_changes_100):

> The two main classes to specify a topology via the DSL
> (KStreamBuilder) or the Processor API (TopologyBuilder) were
> deprecated and replaced by StreamsBuilder and Topology (both new
> classes are located in package org.apache.kafka.streams). Note, that
> StreamsBuilder does not extend Topology, i.e., the class hierarchy is
> different now. The new classes have basically the same methods as the
> old ones to build a topology via DSL or Processor API. However, some
> internal methods that were public in KStreamBuilder and
> TopologyBuilder but not part of the actual API are not present in the
> new classes any longer.